# Убрать рамки приложения

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Вот код, сможешь изменить его? я просто только начал и сам не понимаю куда это внедрять?

https://pastebin.com/3UShFKp9

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'guiv2.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.2
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(250, 280)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(250, 280))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(250, 280))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("font: 8pt \"Arial\";")
        MainWindow.setAnimated(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("#centralwidget {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(39, 39, 39);\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(68, 13, 45, 13))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 87 8pt \"Arial Black\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.work = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.work.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(115, 13, 65, 13))
        self.work.setStyleSheet("font: 87 8pt \"Arial Black\";\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 0);")
        self.work.setObjectName("work")
        self.start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.start.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(74, 240, 103, 31))
        self.start.setStyleSheet("font: 87 8pt \"Arial Black\";\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 170, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.start.setObjectName("start")
        self.progress = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progress.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(75, 37, 126, 13))
        self.progress.setStyleSheet("QProgressBar::chunk "
                          "{"
                          "background-color: rgb(0, 170, 255);"
                          "color: rgb(0, 170, 255);"
                          "}")
        self.progress.setTextVisible(False)
        self.progress.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progress.setObjectName("progress")
        self.base_addr = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.base_addr.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 111, 21))
        self.base_addr.setStyleSheet("border-style: outset;\n"
"background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);\n"
"border-width: 1px;\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.base_addr.setObjectName("base_addr")
        self.base = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.base.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(139, 60, 93, 21))
        self.base.setStyleSheet("font: 87 8pt \"Arial Black\";\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 170, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.base.setObjectName("base")
        self.save_addr = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.save_addr.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 111, 21))
        self.save_addr.setStyleSheet("border-style: outset;\n"
"background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);\n"
"border-width: 1px;\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.save_addr.setObjectName("save_addr")
        self.save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.save.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(139, 100, 93, 21))
        self.save.setStyleSheet("font: 87 8pt \"Arial Black\";\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 170, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.save.setObjectName("save")
        self.proxy_use = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.proxy_use.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 132, 170, 17))
        self.proxy_use.setStyleSheet("font: 87 8pt \"Arial Black\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.proxy_use.setObjectName("proxy_use")
        self.proxy_addr = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.proxy_addr.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 159, 111, 21))
        self.proxy_addr.setStyleSheet("border-style: outset;\n"
"background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);\n"
"border-width: 1px;\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.proxy_addr.setObjectName("proxy_addr")
        self.proxy = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.proxy.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(139, 158, 93, 23))
        self.proxy.setStyleSheet("font: 87 8pt \"Arial Black\";\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 170, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.proxy.setObjectName("proxy")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(76, 200, 70, 21))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 87 8pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.potok = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.potok.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(131, 200, 42, 22))
        self.potok.setStyleSheet("font: 87 8pt \"Arial\";")
        self.potok.setMinimum(1)
        self.potok.setMaximum(100)
        self.potok.setObjectName("potok")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Статус:"))
        self.work.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Работает"))
        self.start.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Начать"))
        self.base.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать"))
        self.save.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить"))
        self.proxy_use.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Использовать прокси"))
        self.proxy.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Потоков:"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `QWidget::setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы убрать рамку достаточно вызвать: `self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)`. Это скажет операционной системе, что рамку не нужно показывать для окна, но это лишит возможности перемещать окно

Действия:

- Сохранил код из вопрос в `MainWindow_ui.py`
- [Взял мой пример окна без рамки и с возможность перемещать окно мышкой](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/00b9e4ec67e3413ffefa436a98381a75b99af6d3/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt__mouse_manual_move__FramelessWindowHint.py#L11)
- Немного подправил и добавил форму из `MainWindow_ui`

Код:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

from MainWindow_ui import Ui_MainWindow


class Widget(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self._old_pos = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self._old_pos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self._old_pos = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self._old_pos:
            return

        delta = event.pos() - self._old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.resize(400, 400)
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

Выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: gil9red я изменил свой вопрос, там ссылка на pastebin, я просто создал это в qt designer и не понимаю что куда ставить, я начинаю лишь. Буду очень благодарен если выделишь немножко времени  

Comment: @unf1ne, вопрос должен быть самодостаточным, поэтому лучше помимо ссылки приложите код. А так, вам только `self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)` добавить в конструктор виджета и всё, это и будет ответом на ваш вопрос :) А методы mouse*Event просто полезная вещь

Comment: у меня не получается его добавить  

Comment: @unf1ne, обновил вопрос (в следующий раз сделаете сами ;)) и ответ (с вас много плюсов и принятие ответа :D) :)

Comment: спасибо большое, не понял что произошло но спасибо за помощь!! дай вам бог здоровья :DDD

Comment: @unf1ne, ок, объясню: код из `MainWindow_ui.py` описывает форму, его нельзя менять, поэтому мы создали класс от `QMainWindow` и `Ui_MainWindow`. В конструкторе класса вызвали метод `setupUi` из `Ui_MainWindow`, чтобы виджеты и настройки из формы применились для нашего виджета. После добавил строчку, чтобы убрать рамку и код с `self._old_pos`, чтобы можно было окно таскать мышкой, т.к. без рамки окна только так можно будет перемещать окно